# Win8 not booting after dual-boot install of 13.04!

Tags: installation, dual-boot

My problem seems to be the reverse of most!!

Fully functional Win8/64-bit laptop, performed dual-boot install of v13.04 per instructions on LinuxBSDos.com forums.

I expected the machine to boot to Windows to complete last step (tweak of boot loader), but instead I can only get into the Ubuntu install!

No bootloader screen, no selection, just right into Ubuntu!

All existing Win8 partitions are still intact when finished installing 13.04, so just looking for some help on where to go from here.

It has been years since I worked with Linux much, so not familiar with the tools in the curernt release!

Answer (score 0):

I too was not able to boot into Win after installing U13.04 (but for a different reason). 
Try installing [grub customizer](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-grub-customizer-302-in-ubuntu.html). It helped me to rectify my problem. Its a GUI editor for grub. Once installed it can be accessed through the launcher. Check if Win8 loader option exist. Be careful. Don't edit anything. Just check for Win8 boot-loader option.

I would also recommend running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Yash!  Looks like the Ubuntu install inserted a new boot entry in the CMOS boot order above the Windows UEFI option, causing it to completely ignore Windows.  I rearranged the boot order in CMOS, and I could then get Windows to boot, but now having issues with Ubuntu booting after the EasyBCD tweaks!  New problem for the morning!!  :)

Comment: what message are you getting?

Comment: Yash, at this point I'm getting the old-fashioned white-on-black Windows error after selecting Ubuntu from the Win OS selection screen that basically says "Sorry, can't load Windows!"  Tried tweaking the boot loader in EasyBCD from "Grub Legacy" to "Grub 2" but to no effect.  Google'ing for more info now...

Comment: I have spent a lot of time (3 days if you believe me) trying to boot ubuntu from Win8 boot menu using EasyBCD. It did not work. I gave up as I felt like I was chasing my own tail. What I did is, reinstall Win8 in "non-UEFI" mode(fresh copy) and then U13.04 in "non-UEFI" mode.